# What's the proper height for brackets around integrals and summations?

Tags: brackets

What's the proper height for brackets around integrals and summations? Are there typesetting convetions for these cases?

E.g., I have this equation:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\[
X \big[ i\sum_{XZY}  {\cal F} A_{XZY}c_{1,+-}  \big]
  =-2 Z \big[ \sum_{\overline{XZY}}  i
    {\cal F} A_{XZY}c_{1,+-} \big] \, .
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm exploring a solution involving the `mleftright` package:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{mleftright}   

\begin{document}

\[
X \mleft[ i\sum_{XZY}  {\cal F} A_{XZY}c_{1,+-}  \mright]
  =-2 Z \mleft[ \sum_{\overline{XZY}}  i
    {\cal F} A_{XZY}c_{1,+-} \mright] \, .
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personal preference. I normally use `\Bigl ... \Bigr`. This is a classic case where most people agree that `\left...\right` is not the correct way to go, they are excessive. When I edit manuscripts (20years of experience with that BTW) I use the following rule of thumb: It should be clear for the reader what is being fenced in, but not to such an extend that the fences take the focus of the equation. With the addendum that in many cases, if the fence is far from a tall object, then there is probably no need to scale it to cover that tall object.

Comment: On the other size, if near a tall object, like here a sum, scaling is needed. As long as the choice is consistent then things are fine. Just don rely on `\left/right` being used everywhere. it looks horrible.

Comment: @campa Edited (it was a typo since I used it to compare `\mleft` and `\lerft`...).

Comment: `\mleft`/`\mright` just fix the excess spacing *around* the fences, not the size, which is chosen exactly like `\left`/`\right`.

Comment: @egreg I know. What would you use in this case?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Either `\Big` size or `\bigg` (slight preference for the former as there is no upper limit; don't forget `\,` after `\Bigl[` in the formula at the right-hand side.